# Setup a WinRt App with a reference to a Class Library which has a reference to a Class Library

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

So my project structure is as follows:
I have a  Class Library that I am using made by XamlToolkit, since I had to tweak a certain handler I now have an implementation of my own. 
This implementation is added as a reference to my BaseApp Class Library which contains Resource Dictionaries and some Code files for controls and such.

This BaseApp library builds into a Dll fine and using the "Generate library layout" option under Build options most issues got solved.
Now in the main WinRt app i have a reference to the BaseApp library and I try to merge the styles into the app as followed:

`<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///BaseApp/CoreFile.xaml" />
</Application.Resources>`

This leaves me with the following error:
An error occurred while finding the resource dictionary "ms-appx:///BaseApp/CoreFile.xaml"

My first question would be, why is this not working? The source declaration should be no problem.
The second question would be, is it even possible to do something such as Class Library to Class Library to WinRt App?

Edit:

In a WinRT project you normally use a Source such as "/Folder/File.xaml". Like Kristian says you need to use the ms-appx:// syntax to reference another project (such as my class library).

The missing key is that in the Class library however you need to use the ms:appx// for all the source declarations to combine the files into 1 resource dictionary like we did in the CoreFile

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to reference class library A in class library B, and then reference class library B in WinRT project. There should be no problem. But if you want to use code from A in WinRT project, then your WinRT project need to reference A too.

If `CoreFile.xaml` is in the root directory of the `BaseApp` class library then your code should work but instead you need to write like this in `App.xaml`:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///BaseApp/CoreFile.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

I never used the `Generate library layout` option and never got any problems, so I think this may be not needed, to prevent errors.

Comment: Kristian you nearly gave the correct answer :) it was a pain to figure out but you have to use the ms-appx:// syntax for EVERY source declaration in the class library.